# Can all regular surfaces be represented as an implicit function

Tags: differential-geometry

I was recently learning about regular surfaces, as defined [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularSurface.html), in my differential geometry class.

I just want to know, whether or not it's possibly to represent any regular surface with a continuous, and differentiable function $F(x,y,z)$ as a solution to $F(x,y,z) = 0$. Like a sphere of radius 1 would be $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

No, a regular surface $S$ cannot always be represented as the  locus of zeros $F(x,y,z)=0$ of a differentiable function $F$ because that locus is closed whereas $S$ needn't be.
A typical example of a non-closed surface in $\mathbb R^3$ is the Möbius band.

On the other hand Whitney has proved that **any** closed subset of any $\mathbb R^n$ is the zero-locus of  a suitable differentiable function $F\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ .
That knocks you for a loop, eh! [It would be a bad sign if it didn't :-)]

Comment: There is much, much more to say on the subject but pedagogy is in part the art of shutting up...

Comment: Does the word "closed" here mean "compact and oriented."?

Comment: No, "closed" just  means closed in the usual topology of $\mathbb R^n$.  No compactness, no orientability required.